# x_subscription_id For Authorize.net

Tags: civicontribute, authorize.net

I am trying to test recurring transactions that were failing in production and in a dev instance.

For testing I am using the curl command from https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/authorize-net/#online-form-testing-method.
`curl https://dev.domain.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/authorizeIPN.php -d x_amount=0.25 -d x_cust_id=9025 -d x_invoice_num=5273 -d x_trans_id=12345TEST`

This is what I am finding in my CiviCRM log.  I see the form example in the book has x_subscription_id but not the curl command.

Dec 19 04:54:55  [info] Could not find an entry for x_subscription_id

Dec 19 04:54:55  [info] $error data = Array
(
    [error_code] => 0
)

Dec 19 04:54:55  [info] $REQUEST = Array
(
    [x_amount] => 0.25
    [x_cust_id] => 9025
    [x_invoice_num] => 5273
    [x_trans_id] => 12345TEST
)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `-d x_subscription_id=21930455` in your curl command (just change it to your subscription_id).

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, now I am getting Could not find an entry for x_response_code.

Comment: ` -d x_response_code=1`
For more info about variables, please checkout sample <form> tag on the Authorize.net CiviCRM documentation page

Comment: Okay, when I figure this out I will update the docs.